# C Programming bottom line independently of other output

Tags: c

I have a question, how to implement in C program bottom line for custom needs and the other part of terminal for program output? Please do not suggest ncurses. For example `apt get some_app`, it doesn't clear terminal, it doesn't use ncurses I suppose, but at the bottom line we can see installation progress but the main program output we can see and scroll any time.

For example, we have multi thread program, in every thread it prints "Hello world\n", I need possibility to scroll all strings up and down and prompt at the bottom of terminal for user input.

Comment: @Kalana I have a big multithread project to add this feature. It's not important what the code is, I need some tip in what way should I go. Excuse my English.

Comment: Then you have to provide us more details like what are you trying to do?, what have you tried so far?, what result do you expect?, In which point do you need our help? likewise. Please add that details clearly Unless it will lead to primly opinion based answers and your question will be closed

Comment: [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) and some [POSIX terminal interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_terminal_interface). Most people suggest ncurses, because what you will do is just reinventing the wheel. Sources of `apt` are open, search them to know how it does that.

Comment: @user3121023 I think it will be not the best solution to jump from the bottom line to the program output every symbol. Maybe you talk about other way?

Comment: @Kalana I have been edit my question a little bit. Is it clear now?

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you, I will look in the sources of "apt".